# Regular expression that won't include whitespace at the end of the match

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression similar to the following:

```
(PART 1)?\s*(PART 2)?\s*(PART 3)?
```

Parts 1, 2 and 3 may or may not be present, and may or may not be separated by whitespace. The above almost works, except it has a tendency to pull out a space at the end of the match if the final part(s) aren't present. For example, it will pull out a space in the following match (where I've added the arrows to show the start and end of the match):

```
-->(PART 1) (PART 2) <--(PART 4)
```

How can I prevent it from doing this? I've tried using lookaheads, but I can only work out how to prevent a space which is at the end of the line, not the end of the match. I've also tried using lazy qualifiers on the spaces, but then it doesn't pull out subsequent parts.

Comment: Please post the examples you have tested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this RegEx:

```
(PART 1)?(\s*PART 2)?(\s*PART 3)?
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/aM8aG6/1)</kbd>

---

How it works:

```
(PART 1)?       # Selects PART 1
(\s*PART 2)?    # Selects Whitespace then PART 2
(\s*PART 3)?    # Selects Whitespace then PART 3
```

Basically, it will only select Whitespace if it proceeds the next part

Comment: It's so obvious when you put it like that, I must have been staring at it too long! Thanks!

Comment: @JamesBaker I know what you mean, I have done the same! `;)`